# how to save csv like text file in an ArrayList to sort by name

Tags: java

i have the below format of textfile:

```
1345, Mike Douglas, 102, 120, 100, 322 
1879, John Bobber, 200, 180, 120, 500 
2560, Andrew Beck, 150, 300, 150, 600 
3212, Rick Water, 200, 100, 140, 440
```

I need to read this file and store it in an `ArrayList`. But I am not getting an Idea which way of storing would be better, so that I can sort the data based on name later on.
please someone throw light on it. I am not asking for code, just an idea and i would implement it.

what I have in my mind is to store each line in a ArrayList but how to sort it later on is my problem.

Comment: Create a class, let's called Person. Then read each line, split it to get the different parts, create a new Person and add it to the list. Then sorting it later would be easy, providing a custom comparator to `Collections.sort`, telling that you want to sort your `List` based on person's name.

Comment: @ZouZou you should post that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class, let's called `Person`. Then read each line, split it to get the different parts, create a new `Person` and add it to the list. Then sorting it later would be easy, providing a custom comparator to `Collections.sort`, telling that you want to sort your `List` based on person's name.

Comment: Have one field for firstName and another one for lastName, to make comparisons easier. Your class should extend Comparable<Person>, it is more clear than a Comparator if there is only one sensible way to compare Persons.

Comment: thanks let me try. I have upvoted your answer. Once i implement i will accept it. if any doubts i will comment here

Comment: I need to use bubble sort..how could I ? I have created a class with all fields with getters and setters..looped through the file and split each line with comma, set the data and added object to list..now i have a written a method for bubble sort which accepts array and then sorts ..how can I use in this scenario

Comment: @susheel You can have the signature `static void bubbleSort(List<Person> persons, Comparator<Person> comp)` (you can use generics to have a more generic method that will sort an array of type T), then use the return value of the method `compare` of the comparator to decide if you have to swap the two persons you are comparing in your sort.